# Disable a touch screen button on dell xps 11

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my dell xps 11  and it is all running well except there is a windows button (super) on the bottom of the touch screen.

This is extremely sensitive and whenever I go near it, it minimizes all my windows and opens the dashboard.

I am trying to disable this key, I have tested and using showkey it appears to register as keycode 125, which is the same as the super key on the actual keyboard.

So my question is can I disable one without affecting the other and if so how would you recommend going about this ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: glad to see you install 14.04 on the xps 11. Are some hardware or functionality unsupported by 14.04? Can you control the pressure for the touch keyboard? How is the keyboard usability compared to Windows? Regards,
Emmanuel

Comment: The only problem I have with it is this phantom pressing of the touch screen button, the wifi works, the touchscreen just works fine and the keyboard takes some getting used to but after a while feels very nice

Answer (score 0):

If you run xev and then press the button, it will show you the key code that is being sent by that button.

Then you can run this command

```
 xmodmap -e 'keycode number = NoSymbol'
```

where you replace "number" with the keycode shown.